# Sorting points by a changing date found in another CSV files attributes table

Tags: sorting, date, spatial, qgis, temporal

**The Question:**
I am studying lions, and their kill sites.
I currently have around 890 historic kill site locations with their recorded date in a clean CSV file (with some other attribute info). The data is old and I am looking to confirm the reliability of it (looking for additional proof) by looking at the collar (movement) data (multiple GPS locations) of the lions over the time around when the kills were recorded (this is a separate CSV file).
So, within a 300m radius of each Kill location I am looking to see what movement happened within the 300m area 3 months before and 2 weeks after the kill (date) was recorded.

I have tried all I know and can (unfortunately my knowledge on any code is limited) - buffer around each kill, have clipped the points that fall within the 300m area  (have created a separate CSV file) easily but cannot separate and sort them to confirm if there was a kill or not.

I am using 3.26.2-Buenos Aires and have tried sending it to multiple forums (where I was requested to use Database manager with a certain SQL code - but I received a syntax error and couldn't find my way past it) and have googled the issues at every hurdle I have got to, but (within my knowledge) I have not been able to get an efficient way to tackle this issue. I am happy to do part of it manually but there are 890 kill sites, so hoping I won’t need to spend more than 1 minute per kill site.